# Cause of High Disk Queue Length in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, performance

I have a fairly high-throughput application that occasionally decides to collapse on me. It's not very often - about once every ~3 weeks or so. When it does, if I check out perfmon, I see 100% "Avg. Disk Queue Length" pegging the server.

During these times, I also see lots of nice connection failed messages from SQL Server.

I'm no SQL Server expert, I can do the basics for indexing, taking backups, etc., but that's it.

What would cause something like this? I was thinking perhaps it was a resize of the database (it was down to ~300MB available [and it's a 30 gig database]), or maybe some reindexing gone nuts?

I do have one table in particular that has tons of inserts. *Very* few reads, but many inserts per second isn't unusual at all.

The server has only ~4 gig of RAM as well, but we do have a dedicated warehouse box that rolls up data every night where *most* of the heavy querying is directed.

Anyone got any thoughts on what might cause that huge queue length?

Comment: In Windows, the "average queue length" is roughly analogous to what Unixes would call "iowait."  Check your hardware health.

Comment: Monitor your table scans, as well as how often your instance needs to reach out to disk as opposed to the data cache.  Could be hardware, but could also be an underlying cause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so, from what I can tell, it was related to a bunch of things:

1. resizing files (data and log both)
2. large number of inserts happening while 1. was going on
3. one particularly heavy query running while 1. was going on
4. a hard drive with some pretty high i/o times in general
5. lack of memory on the server, so hitting the page file on top of everything else

Here were my resolutions:

1. change the autogrowth settings so I'd have consistent growth when it happens, manually grew both the temp and primary database files to have more space, added additional vlogs to the temp database, and set up a notification so I can manually grow when the database gets below a certain space level.
2. [nothing to be done about it]
3. made the heavy query run less often; it was loading up data the user didn't always need, so changed it to run on-demand
4. [working on getting a new server, this app is growing fast]
5. [working on getting a new server, this app is growing fast]

So, anyway, it was a combination of a whole bunch of different things, mostly related to SQL, but not exclusively (so Will was correct there).

I'd love to split the answer between everyone, as they had portions of it right, but what can you do...

Answer (score 2):

Wait for a moment where the disk queue depth is high and find all currently running queries (scripts available on the web). It is likely that some expensive query is running. Examples: Data warehouse style queries, index operations, DBCC CHECKDB, shrinking, ... All of these are designed to drive the IO system with all might.

Comment: Yeah, I ran this: http://www.frozenmountain.com/Blog/post/Analyzing-Long-Running-SQL-Queries-without-Profiler.aspx, and ended up with just the one highly optimized query I expected. Is my query not showing the right info (i.e., excluding index ops?)

Comment: Most queries should show up there. Very rarely, some background task like ghost cleanup does not show up.

Answer (score 1):

High Disk Queue Length can be caused by a number of things, not *just* SQL Server:

- Hardware failing, or misbehaving (as Charles mentions in the comments). eg: RAID controller or disks, network cards too (potentially).
- Buggy Drivers (almost any part of the system - disk controllers, memory controllers, network drivers)
- Other applications running. eg: Disk scans, Backups, Defragmentation, Windows Indexing, Virus Scans.
- Other users eg: copying files to/from the drive.

If SQL Server needs to expand it's files (data, log), that could be a potential cause too if you have a slow or fragmented disk.

Windows Server 2008 and up has Resource Monitor, which allows you to see what operations are occurring on the disk.  Total Bytes/sec is one indicator, but it could be lots of small operations also occurring.

Comment: Hmmm...do you happen to know at what point SQL auto-expands its files? I was down to 300MB available according the sp_spaceused sproc...

Comment: Oh, and unfortunately, I'm stuck on 2k3 :(

Answer (score 0):

> Anyone got any thoughts on what might cause that huge queue length?

The disc subsystem just being too pathetic to handle the load. Check whether anything special goes on during those times. If not - maybe jsut get a cheap SSD ;)

Answer (score 0):

In our case it was caused by a query in UPDATE trigger on one of the main tables in the database. The query was inserting into the log tables from temp DELETED table. We changed the query to use INSERTED table and it solved the problem.